# node.js and Serial ports

Tags: node.js, serial-port, barcode-scanner, jquery-barcode

I'm trying to build a simple web app that reads the clients' serial port that is connected to a barcode scanner. I have done this using ActiveX but it only works on IE browsers, i have heard that I can now do this using node.js and serial-node. Can someone tell me if this is even possible using these two technologies? Also if anyone can direct me to a working tutorial on how to do this. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript interface with RS-232 Serial Port](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592099/javascript-interface-with-rs-232-serial-port)

Comment: (Barcode readers that emulate keyboard keypresses are so much more awesome as they don't need COM ports or USB drivers!)

Comment: Well, not so awes39123439ome when they start typing codes into a SO comme39123440nt box.  Getting a wire long enough to connect the bar code scanner to the web server ought to be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can't read the serial port of the web app's client's computer using serial-node, no.  Node.js and serial-node run server side, they do not have direct access to the web clients' hardware.